# Is there some advantage of using NVidia optimus when on AC adapter?

Tags: intel, nvidia, optimus

I have installed **NVidia** graphics card on my notebook, which supports **Optimus** technology (second graphics card is integrated on the **Intel** processor).

Suppose, I am with my notebook on AC adapter **forever** (or at least 99% of my work with notebook) - is there any advantage of preferring **optimus** option over **discrete graphics card**?

Comment: think this belongs on superuser

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will consume less electricity and thus pay less on your provider :)

On some laptops, it also enable the CPU to run at full speed, while it's not the case when the discrete GPU is activated (due to global thermal profile).